# XMLSerialization with WCF Enum Attribute ignored

Tags: wcf, attributes, xml-serialization

I am having problem with serializing object before send to the wire.

Basically I am expecting my object to be serialized as

```
<verb operation="and">Show</verb>
```

However its ignoring the attribute as

```
<verb>Show</verb>
```

Below is the client proxy code

```
    /// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "3.0.4506.2152")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport")]
public enum OperationEnumeratedType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    /// 
    and,

    /// <remarks/>
    /// 
    or,

    /// <remarks/>
    /// 
    not,
}


        /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public OperationEnumeratedType operation
    {
        get
        {
            return this.operationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.operationField = value;
        }
    }
```

and Below is How I am Creating this object.

```
                    verb = new CriteriaLogicStringType
                    {
                        operation = OperationEnumeratedType.and,
                        Value = "Show"
                    }
```

Does anyone knows how can I get the Operation Attribute to appear in serialized xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decorate the members of the `OperationEnumeratedType` enumeration with the [EnumMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute.aspx), like this:

```
[DataContract]
public enum OperationEnumeratedType
{
    [EnumMember]
    And,
    [EnumMember]
    Or, 
    [EnumMember]
    Not
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [Enumeration Types in Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately I am limited to use the generated proxy class which is using XmlSerialization. Do you know how to achive this using XmlSerialization?

Comment: @activebiz How do you send the request to the service?

Comment: I use the WCF proxy which is using ClientBase. I have tried above but its same result. Is it becouse I have rest of the proxy using XmlSerilizer ?